# link_to issue with inherited Active Record class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

Here are the classes as I have them set up:

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :stats_parent
end

class TotalStat < Stat
    belongs_to :stats_parent
end

#The StatsParent class is just to show how I use the relation.
class StatsParent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one  :total_stat
    has_many :stats
end
```

For the Stats Controller index action:

```
def index
    @stats = Stat.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @stat }
    end
end
```

In the index view for stats there is this bit of code:

```
<% @stats.each do |stat| %>
    ...
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', stat %></td>
<% end %>
```

And I get this error:

```
undefined method `total_stat_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000010324c1f8>
```

Why cant the link_to work here?  Do I need to create a separate controller to handle the `TotalStat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's clearly an STI(single table inheritance) issue there, though I'd need to see more code to see what's really up.  A quick fix would be to be more specific about the link_to path:

```
<%= link_to "Show", stat_path(stat) %>
```

Comment: The method stat_path() is generated somewhere.  Could you point me to any doc that describes what method like this are generated for me?

Comment: When you create a resource in your routes with map.resources :stats you get a bunch of routes for free.  Check out section 3 in the routing guide for a better understanding of the routing methods you get from RESTful resources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restful-routing-the-rails-default